# retrieving global parameter in hadoop reducer returns null

Tags: hadoop, global, reducers

I set a global variable for job like this:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();   
    Job job = new Job(conf, "new_job"); 
     conf.set("attribute", "value");
```

I accessed it in the reducer like this, and checked the value:

```
Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
    attribute = conf.get("attribute");
    System.out.println("attribute:"+attribute);
```

but its value printed as null, also

> NullPointerException

is encountered when I tried to use the retrieved variable

> attribute

later in the code.

Please help me to find out what's going wrong.

Comment: you code should work.your attribute  Type  is String.  did you check  stdout reducer log  web console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing the conf into the Job eventually copies the properties from the configuration object. You should set the attributes before constructing the Job

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();   
conf.set("attribute", "value");
Job job = new Job(conf, "new_job");
```